# How to add user in a people and group column of sharepoint 2010 list using javascript only?

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript

[image: This is the code which i have used.]

I am doing this. Where "Login" is the column name, and "CurrentUserId" is the value which i want to add in the column. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use FieldLookupValue to set the value for the "Person or group" field. You just need to set the value for the field like for any other standard type of field. Also, you should use the name of the column, without the addition of "Id" (`Login` instead of `LoginId` in your example):

```
oListItem.set_item('Login', CurrentUserId);
oListItem.update();
clientContext.load(oListItem);
```

The code that you pasted can be used to set the value of a lookup colum. If, for example, you had your other custom list called Logins, with user details, and one of the columns in your list is a lookup column to Logins list (column called Login), you could set the field value with your code, with one small change (the name of the column should be `Login`, instead of `LoginId`)

The updated code would look like this:

```
var LoginLookUp = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
LoginLookUp.set_lookupId(CurrentUserId);
oListItem.set_item('Login', LoginLookUp);
oListItem.update();
clientContext.load(oListItem);
```